# Image not loading, Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed

Tags: php, nginx, magento2

I have the following problem on a Magento2 Fresh installation with dummy data, using the theme [Revo]: https://themeforest.net/item/revo-responsive-magento-2-shopping-theme/18339484

> Error filtering template: Warning:
>   getimagesize(https://website.com/media/wysiwyg/imageslider/slider-1.jpg):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
>   in
>   /var/www/html/nobacco/vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/AbstractAdapter.php
>   on line 304

Permissions are correct, nginx settings seem good the image exists on the server and is accessible through the same url and the user rights seems alright too.. Any ideas?
Before this error I was getting an error on vendor/(cant remember the full path)/Image.php

Comment: Please move your question to Server Fault.

Comment: update error message formatting